# Compare Value list in Guava MultiMap

Tags: java, data-structures, multimap

I have a multimap as below:

```
key1 : [Val1, Val2, Val3,...]
key2 : [Val4, Val5, Val6,...]
```

The values for Key1 are not unique (thanks to Multimaps).

I have to find the unique values for Key1 and do the average of corresponding key2 values(integers). For example, compare Val1 with all the other values of key1 and find that Val1 and Val3 are the same strings. Now keep Val1/Val3 and do average(Val4,Val6) present in Key2. How can I access values inside the list?

Adding the code and the output:

Code:

```
String patternString = "(fileName\":\"|dur\":|tdur\":)([^\",]*)";

            Multimap<String, String> multimap1 = ArrayListMultimap.create();

            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

                for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    if(line.contains(".js\"")&&(line.contains("\"name\":\"v8.run\"")&&(line.contains("fileName\":")&&(line.contains("dur\":")&&(line.contains("tdur\"")))))){

                        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternString).matcher(line);
                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            multimap1.put(matcher.group(1).replaceAll(("\".*"),"_R"),matcher.group(2)); 

                            }

                    }

                    else if(line.contains(".js\"")&&(line.contains("\"name\":\"v8.compile\"")&&(line.contains("fileName\":")&&(line.contains("dur\":")&&(line.contains("tdur\""))))))
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            for (String key : multimap1.keySet()){
                System.out.println(key + ":" + multimap1.get(key));
                        }
```

Output:

```
fileName_R:[http://localhost/NotMyScript.js,http://localhost/MyScript.js, http://localhost/MyScript.js]
tdur_R:[40, 37, 16]
dur_R:[46, 87, 17]
```

I have to average tdur_R(i.e. 37 & 16) and dur_R (i.e. 87 & 17), if the js name matches (i.e. http://localhost/MyScript.js). Hope I am clearer this time.

Comment: I'm sorry, is there a question here, or did you just want to tell us you are new to multimaps and that you are gonna do this?

Comment: You mention "average" then say "same string".  You can't do an average of a string; what's the concrete and actual types that you're working with?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Values in the list for Key2 are integers.

Comment: Edited OP with current code. Cheers!!